# How getCalendarById(id) work if the setting is made public and all ids are accessible in an organization

Tags: javascript, web, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using google app script for calender events,
According to document: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById%28String%29

returned value is the calendar with the given ID, or null if the calendar does not exist or the user cannot access it
say in an orgainzation windows.com the setting is made where all ids in the org are accessible,

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('mac@windows.com');
   Logger.log(cal);
```

It gives `null` if I run the function and when I manually subscribe the mac@windows.com to the calender of the authorized script runner then it works fine,

**Is there a way where we can get the id of the organization subscribe while running the script, for dynamic input of id.**

Calender setting in the org google business app is : Share this calender with everyone in the organization windows.com as default.

Comment: I think you are making a confusion between calendar name and ID. Check the getByName method.

Comment: @Sergeinsas i looked for the same and thats not my query, actually how can I subscribe or add the cowerkers calender in the org through the google app script, because this is working for those ids/names which are subscribed to the id which is auth for the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in a recent project and discovered that the user must be explicitly subscribed to the calendar for the GetCalendarById function to work reliably.  I used the following code to handle this, it attempts to subscribe the user if getCalendarById fails to return it on the first try.

I also set the calendar to hidden & un-selected, so subscribing the user does not clutter their standard calendar view.

```
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar_id);
  if(calendar == null){
    //user may not have access, auto-subscribe them.
    calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(calendar_id,{hidden:true,selected:false});
  }
```

See the calendarApp reference, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#subscribeToCalendar(String,Object)

Comment: The first and second calendar_id are same or different

Comment: I am trying to run this code but it is not working for me..Any suggestion?