# How to get Calendar Id from user's email using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a Google calendar event for the user who submits leave request on google form. When this form response is recorded in google sheets, I get the user email id and want to create a calendar event for them. Script creates event when I use my email id, but it gives null when I try to do the same for other user.

Here is the sample code:

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email)
        .createAllDayEvent(
            'OOO - Out Of Office',
            startDate,
            endDate,
            {
              description: message,
              sendInvites: true,
            });
```

I received this error: **Cannot read property "createAllDayEvent" of null**

I googled this error, and [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645439/how-getcalendarbyidid-work-if-the-setting-is-made-public-and-all-ids-are-acces) suggested that subscribing to user's calendar may solve this issue. I used the following snippet to counter that:

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email);
  if(calendar == null){
    //user may not have access, auto-subscribe them.
    calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(email,{hidden:true,selected:false});
  }
```

But it is showing a new error stating: **The calendar or calendar event does not exist, it was deleted, or the user doesn't have access to it**

Any idea how we can make it work. Thank you.

Comment: In your situation, whose calendar do you want to use? For example, do you want to create the events in your Calendar? Or, do you want to create an event in each user's Calendar?

Comment: I want to create an event in each user's calendar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want to create an event in each user's calendar.`, in this case, unfortunately, I think that Google Form might not be suitable. Because when Google Form is submitted, the script is run by the owner. So for example, when each user's calendar is shared with you, you can achieve your goal. But when you cannot access to the user's calendar, your goal cannot be achieved. In that case, I think that the custom form using Web Apps might be suitable. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: there are multiple users which are recording their responses. So their email ids are also recorded in the google sheet. Are you saying that we can not get the calendar of users by their ids even after subscribing to their calendar? just like this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645439/how-getcalendarbyidid-work-if-the-setting-is-made-public-and-all-ids-are-acces)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: No, don't be sorry. I request you to please suggest anything so that we can create an event in the user's calendar using his email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this on Form Response (at least not reliably).

To create an event in another user's calendar they must have changed their calendar settings to be available to the public and the Access Permissions must be set to 'Make changes to events'. More information about this can be read on [this help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082#controlaccess&zippy=%2Cunderstand-permission-settings-for-shared-calendars)

If these settings aren't set by the user, you're out of luck creating events for them. In this case you have two options:

1. Create an OAuth2 Application which the user authenticates to allow the creation of Calendar events on their behalf (though this still can't be done on form submit)
2. Create an event on *your* calendar and send them an invitation using their email address. You can give them edit permissions to the event so that they have control of it as if it were in their calendar, though in this case they will have to accept the event invitation.

Comment: Ok..Thank you. I guess we are stuck here then.